# Does it help if you learn to play certain instruments both right-handed and left-handed?

Tags: technique

I once heard that if you switch hands when the violin, guitar or any other instrument that each hand has a separate task, it enhances your technical capabilities in music, general technique, and is good for your brain, is that so?

Comment: I would guess that it's fun as a mental exercise, but I'm not sure it would make any difference in your technique, since you're doing the exact opposite of the regular technique.

Comment: If I switch my hands on guitar I'm completely and utterly useless.  I'm normally alright with swapping on other tasks (at one point I could throw a baseball properly with my off hand/arm) but I think spending time on this would just be a waste.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the links to the original scientific data related to the question. The question is great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only times I find myself doing this is when, as a teacher, I need to remember how it was to be a beginner. I don't think this is a particularly bad idea but I reckon there's much more useful ways to spend your practice time.

As a side-note:

This is just my opinion but I never really understood why would people play guitar left handed. The left hand is actually the one that does most of the work so lefties benefits from playing right-handed guitars.